# Is there a fast algorithm for computing the Schmidt decomposition

Tags: ds.algorithms, matrices

I have a huge covariance matrix, , with the dimension, e.g., $10^8 \times 10^8$. Luckily enough, the number of nonzero eigenpairs, $n$, is very small, i.e., $n<5$. From the computational prospective, I would like to represent, $M$, in Schmidt decompsition as
$$
= \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i {\bf e}_i^T \otimes {\bf e}_i,
$$
where $\lambda_i$ and ${\bf e}_i$ are the nonzero eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M$. This equation can be further written as
$$
= \sum_{i=1}^n {\bf g}_i^T \otimes {\bf g}_i,
$$
where the vectors ${\bf g}_i=\sqrt{\lambda_i}{\bf e}_i$. Using this relation, the matrix, $M$, can be stored in terms of nonzero ${\bf g}_i$ in computer.

My problem is that the matrix, , is changing at every time snapshot. The update of the matrix, , is given by the following formular,
$$
′= \sum_{i=1}^n {\bf g}_i^T \otimes ({\bf g}_i+ \delta {\bf g}_i)+({\bf g}_i+ \delta {\bf g}_i)^T \otimes {\bf g}_i
$$
where $\delta {\bf g}_i$ is the update of the $i$th vector and is small comparing with ${\bf g}_i$. Due to some dynamical properties/constraints, the updated covariance matrix, $M'$, contains the same number of nonzero eigenpairs, $n$.

I wonder whether there is a fast algorithm for computing the new nonzero eigenpairs?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use an iterative decomposition algorithm (like Lanczos or Arnoldi) with one of the singular vectors of the previous time step as a starting vector for the current time step. This speeds up convergence significantly. I am not aware of any theoretical bounds on number of iterations, but a good place to start might be Saad's books: https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/books.html

Comment: Yes, many thanks for your help. Indeed, this method works.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47056/5038, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3723906/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).